# Question regarding software testing about automate test case

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, testcase

nice to meet you all here. I have question about software testing, i am quite new around 6 months in software testing.

My question is:
Can we make automated test case if the test case requires the device to reboot?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your test into two pieces: one before reboot, and the other one after reboot. If you need a specific data for the second piece, you can save the output of first test and then call it during your second test piece.

Comment: Hi is this way of doing is acceptable? I am asking because i am really new in this software testing field.

Comment: I personally used split testing method for some of my automated tests. And it is acceptable as long as it satisfies your needs.